# Can I use some properties file instead Swagger annotations for my Controllers classes in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, swagger

I'm using swagger with spring boot in my project, and there are some API's that I need to use annotations for change some descriptions, parameters names, ou insert examples.

For do it, I need to change my controller, and insert some annotations, for example:

```
    @ApiOperation(value = "Returns a person list")
    @ApiImplicitParams({
       @ApiImplicitParam(name = "Authorization", value = "Access Token", required = true, allowEmptyValue = false, paramType = "header", dataTypeClass = String.class, example = "Bearer access_token"),
       @ApiImplicitParam(name = "X-Custom-Header", value = "A Custom Header", required = true, allowEmptyValue = false, paramType = "header", dataTypeClass = String.class, example = "my header example")
    })
    @RequestMapping(value = "/person", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
    public List<Pessoa> get() {
        return personRepository.findAll();
    }
```

But in some cases, it make my Controller class with a lot of information just because swagger, my question is: There is a way instead of use annotations in my Controller class, use a properties file, or another Class just with the Swagger annotations, something like:

```
myController.myMethod.apiOperation=Returns a person list
```

I knew that i can insert only the value property in the file, but i would like to not use any annotation related to swagger/OpenApi in my controller.